# Can not install NodeJs module

Tags: node.js, module, netcdf4

I have been struggling to install this module for more than two days and I couldn't. Could you please let me know which step I'm missing?

https://github.com/swillner/netcdf4-js

Here is the error I get on nodejs:

```
D:\master\nodeTut>npm install netcdf4

netcdf4@0.3.1 install D:\master\nodeTut\node_modules\netcdf4
node-gyp rebuild

D:\master\nodeTut\node_modules\netcdf4>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild ) else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack at PythonFinder. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\master\nodeTut\node_modules\netcdf4
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\master\nodeTut\package.json'
npm WARN nodeTut No description
npm WARN nodeTut No repository field.
npm WARN nodeTut No README data
npm WARN nodeTut No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! netcdf4@0.3.1 install: node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the netcdf4@0.3.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Ehsan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-06-11T22_02_31_364Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing this package and see if it fixes the issue

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Comment: :\master\nodeTut\node_modules\netcdf4>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  Group.cpp
  File.cpp
  Variable.cpp
  Dimension.cpp

Comment: d:\master\nodetut\node_modules\netcdf4\src\Variable.h(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'netcdf.h': No s
uch file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\Variable.cpp) [D:\master\nodeTut\node_modules\netcdf4\build\netcdf4
.vcxproj]
  Attribute.cpp
..\src\File.cpp(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'netcdf.h': No such file or directory [D:\master\nodeT
ut\node_modules\netcdf4\build\netcdf4.vcxproj]
..\src\Group.cpp(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'netcdf.h': No such file or directory [D:\master\node ...